# Possible relation between $n$ and $l^{h+1}$ if $q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1 \equiv 0 \mod l^{h+1}$ .

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $n \geq 0$ be an integer and $l$ a prime. Can we conclude that if

$q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1 \equiv 0 \mod l^{h+1}$ for some $h \geq 1$ integer, then $l^{h+1} \mid n$? I am asking this because I want to prove that if $l^h$ is the largest power that divides $q-1$ we have that: if $l$ divides $\frac{q^n-1}{(q-1)gcd(n,q-1)}$ then $l^{h+1}$ divides $n$.

If $l$ divides $\frac{q^n-1}{(q-1)gcd(n,q-1)}$, then, since $l^h$ divides $q-1$, then we must have that $l^{h+1}$ divides $q^n-1$. Then $q^n - 1 \equiv 0 \mod l^{h+1}$, therefore $(q-1)(q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1) \equiv 0 \mod l^{h+1}$. Since $l^h$ is the largest power of $l$ that divides $q-1$ we must have $q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1 \equiv 0 \mod l$, since $l$ in particular divides $q-1$ we get that $q \equiv 1 \mod l$ so $n\equiv q^{n-1}+...+1 \equiv 0 \mod l$.

Now $l$ divides $gcd(n,q-1)$, so in fact we get that $l^{h+2}$ must divide $q^n -1$ if $l$ divides $\frac{q^n-1}{(q-1)gcd(n,q-1)}$. We can proceed with the same argument until we get that $l^{2h+1}$ must divide $q^n -1$ (because for any $k \leq h$ we have $q \equiv 1 \mod l^k$). So we get that

$q^n - 1 \equiv (q-1)(q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1 ) \equiv 0 \mod l^{2h+1}$ and again, since $l^h$ is the largest power of $l$ that divides $q-1$ we must have 
 $q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1 \equiv 0 \mod l^{h+1}$. And I want to conclude that $l^{h+1} \mid n$, but I can't go further.

I did it.
I used the following lemma:

> Let $l$ a prime such that $l \mid q-1$, then for any $k \geq 1$,
>   integer, $l^k$ is the largest power of $l$ dividing
>   $\frac{q^{l^k}-1}{(q-1)}$.

So, since we got that $q^n-1 \equiv 0 \mod l^{2h+1}$ and we got as well that $n \equiv 0 \mod l^h$ (this is since $q \equiv 1 \mod l^h$), therefore $n = n_{0}l^h$, we can then write $\frac{q^n-1}{(q-1)gcd(n,q-1)} = \frac{(q^{l^h}-1)C(q)}{(q-1)gcd(n,q-1)}$, where $C(q)= q^{l^h(n_{0}-1)} + \ldots + q^{l^h} + 1$. So, by the previous lemma, $l^h$ is the largest power that divides $(q^{l^h}-1)/(q-1)$, since, by hypothesis, $l^h$ is the largest power dividing $(q-1)$ and, since $l^h$ also divides $n$, it must divide $gcd(n,q-1)$ as well. Therefore $l^{2h+1}$ divides $(q^{l^h}-1)C(q)$. Now, given we have $l^{2h+1}$ upstairs in our fraction and $l^h$ is the largest power that divides $(q^{l^h}-1)/(q-1)$ we can conclude that $l^{h+1}$ divides the quotient $\frac{q^{l^h(n_{0}-1)} + \ldots + q^{l^h} + 1}{gcd(n,q-1)}$. Which implies (since $l^h$ divides $gcd(n,q-1)$) that $l$ divides $q^{l^h(n_{0}-1)} + \ldots + q^{l^h} + 1$, so $q^{l^h(n_{0}-1)} + \ldots + q^{l^h} + 1 \equiv 0 \mod l$ since $q \equiv 1 \mod l$, we have that $n_{0} \equiv 0 \mod l$, so $n = l^hn_{0}$ is a multiple of $l^{h+1}$.

Comment: It reminds me a question from here but I cannot find it anymore on the website

Comment: $q$ is a prime power ? An integer ? Moreover how do you prove dat $\frac{q^n-1}{(q-1)\gcd(n,q-1)}$ is an integer ?

Comment: In the article, $q$ is in fact a prime power, but it is not needed to get this result. To see that $\frac{q^n-1}{(q-1)gcd(n,q-1)}$ is an integer you just need to see that $q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1 \equiv 0 \mod gcd(n,q-1)$, which is true since $q \equiv 1 \mod gcd(n,q-1)$ and $n \equiv 0 \mod gcd(n,q-1)$.

Comment: Maybe you can try an induction on $h$ and use a simplified version of Hensel's lemma. Indeed you have da fact dat $n\equiv 0 \pmod l$ and you can try to build an other element such dat $n\equiv 0 \pmod {l^2}$.

Comment: Tell me if you get it ;)

Comment: Well, actually I did! I had to had to use an additional result! I've edited the main question :)

Comment: Develop da fact dat $n\equiv 0 \pmod{l^h}$ thank ya

Comment: Since we can get that $q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1 \equiv 0 \mod l^{h+1}$, in particular, we have that $q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1 \equiv 0 \mod l^{h}$ (this fact actually happens the other way around in the reasoning). And by hypotesis, $q \equiv 1 \mod l^h$, so $ n \equiv q^{n-1} + \ldots + q + 1 \equiv 0 \mod l^{h}$.

Comment: In yo lemma it's $l$ instead of $h$ right ? Da tricky part of yo question is dat it concerns a quotient, so you have to master da properties of congruences and divisibility homies ;)

Comment: Oh yeah, that's true. It is $l$ indeed. I agree, the point here is the fact you have to get information about $n$ when you have a quotient with some $n$ powers of $q$.

Comment: In general with dis kind of stuff you wanna use Lagrange and Fermat results but here it is just tricky congruences properties. It reminds me Liouville's equation. Do you have a proof of da lemma ma man ?

Comment: Moreova what's da point of dis question and yo subject in "number theory" bro' ?

Comment: Do u have other exercises like dat bro' ?